# I want conditional mongoose query on Js, if Id exits then update and check or create and check

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While function I want to check if `id` exits than I want to update the condition with checking the below function than save. Or else I want to save the entry into `db`.
So to do this which is the correct way for doing this by below code.

```
function saveCompany(company, isDelete, userId) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result = {};
    result.error = null;
    result.res = null;
    try {
        let isAdd = false;

        let useridObj = new ObjectID(userId);
        let user = conn.model(constants.collectionName.user, user_model.userSchema, constants.collectionName.user);
        user.findById(useridObj).exec(function (uerr, user) {
            if (uerr) {
                console.error(uerr);
                let resp = api_respose.getBadRequestResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, uerr.message);
                resolve(resp);
            }
            var cModel = conn.model(constants.collectionName.company, company_model.companySchema, constants.collectionName.company);
            if (!company._id) {
                company.createdDate = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();
                company.createdBy = user.name;
                isAdd = true;
            }
            company.modifiedDate = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString();
            company.modifiedBy = user.name;
            let id = new ObjectID(company._id);
            cModel.findById(id).exec(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    let resp = api_respose.getBadRequestResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, err.message);
                    resolve(resp);
                }
                if (!res) {
                    if (isAdd) {
                        res = new cModel();

                    }
                    else {
                        result.error = "Company was not found with id: " + company._id;
                        console.error("Company was not found with id: " + company._id);
                        let resp = api_respose.getNotFoundResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, result.error);
                        resolve(resp);
                    }
                }
                var lean = JSON.stringify(res);
                res.company_code = company.company_code;
                res.parent_company = company.parent_company;
                res.name = company.name;
                res.abbreviation = company.abbreviation;
                res.care_of = company.care_of;
                res.address_1 = company.address_1;
                res.address_2 = company.address_2;
                res.address_3 = company.address_3;
                res.state = company.state;
                res.zip = company.zip;
                res.addressee = company.addressee;
                res.modifiedBy = user.name;
                res.modifiedDate = company.modifiedDate;
                res.is_deleted = isDelete ? true : company.is_deleted;
                res.is_registered_for = company.is_registered_for;
                res.registered_by = company.registered_by;


                cModel.findOneAndUpdate({ name: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.name}$`, 'i') } }        
                , company, { upsert: true }, function(err, docs) { 
                    if (docs.length) {
                        result.error = "Name already exists: " + company.name;
                        console.log("Name already exists", null);
                        let resp = api_respose.getSuccessResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, result.error);
                        resolve(resp);
                    }
                    else {
                        res.save({ lean: true }, function (tterr, update) {
                            if (tterr) {
                                console.error(tterr);
                                let resp = api_respose.getBadRequestResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, tterr.message);
                                resolve(resp);
                            }
                            if (update) {
                                if (isAdd) {
                                    audit_log.logObjectChanges({}, company, user, constants.auditLogAction.company, conn);
                                }
                                else {
                                    audit_log.logObjectChanges(JSON.parse(lean), isDelete ? {} : company, user, constants.auditLogAction.company, conn);
                                }
                                result.res = update;
                                let resp = api_respose.getSuccessResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, result);
                                resolve(resp);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
             }
            );
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        let resp = api_respose.getBadRequestResponse(process.env.WEB_URI, e.message);
        resolve(resp);
    }

});
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
if (event.httpMethod && event.httpMethod == "OPTIONS") {
    let response = api_respose.getPreflightCorsVallidation(process.env.WEB_URI, event);
    context.succeed(response);
    return;
}
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
if (!conn) {
    conn = await db.connectToDB(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
}

var params = { company: '', isDelete: false, userId: '' };
if (event.body) {
    let rec = JSON.parse(event.body);
    params.company = rec.company;
    params.userId = rec.userId;
    params.isDelete = rec.isDelete;
}
else {
    params.company = event.company;
    params.userId = event.userId;
    params.isDelete = event.isDelete;
}
let result = null;
result = await saveCompany(params.company, params.isDelete, params.userId);
console.log("Final Result on Insert: ", JSON.stringify(result));
return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{upsert:true}` option as follows

```
cModel.update({ name: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${company.name}$`, 'i') } }        
, company, { upsert: true }, function(err, res) { 
    // Deal with the response data/error
});
```

So it will update if the document exists, else it will insert as new document. If you want the newly created doc in response use `{new:true}`

Comment: in `_id:condition` what will be the condition?

Comment: but it will require _id to update the same id while updating?

Comment: @Nandani then just use `update`alone. I have edited my answer

Comment: using update than tell me we have to provide `id` in param  than how while there is no `id` how would it create new insert?

Comment: @Nandani `{upset:true}` will create new id and insert that document if its not there, if the condition satisfies in query it will update that document in the DB.

Comment: updated the question with code, Now it creates 2 entries in mongo DB, Can you help looking into code where actually this happening?

Comment: @Nandani its looks like same as old code you never used the above answer anywhere

Comment: @Nandani My guess is that `cModel.findOneAndUpdate` and `res.save` is happening, so its saving twice, check whether its happening twice in that code block

Answer (score 0):

you can use `upsert: true` option to insert doc into collection if the id doesn't exist in collection, also use `$setOnInsert` to set data only when an `upsert` occur

Example :

```
model.update({id: id},
        {
            "$set": data,
            "$setOnInsert": upsertData,
        },
        {upsert: true});
```